# Passing dynamic parameters to a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have this procedure that executes another procedure passed by a parameter and its parameters `datefrom` and `dateto`.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[execute_proc] 
@procs varchar(200),
@pdatefrom date,
@pdateto date
as

exec @procs  @datefrom=@pdatefrom,@dateto=@pdateto
```

But I need to also pass the parameters dynamically without the need to edit them in the procedure. For example, what I am imagining is something like this

```
 CREATE procedure [dbo].[execute_proc] 
    @procs varchar(200),
    @params varchar(max)
 as
    exec @procs @params
```

where `@params` is a string like `@param1=1,@param2='somethingelse'`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: visit this link: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/stored-procedures-parameters-inserts-and-updates

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you don't know what parameters will be passed to the procedure, how can you use them in the procedure code?

Comment: hmm i don't think it answers my question :(

Comment: Yes I don't know what parameters will be passed to the stored procedure each time, So it will generate the execution each time

Comment: What do you mean "generate the execution each time"? If the parameters can be anything, and if you don't know in advance what they are, then how can you write any code using them?

Comment: Well the actual code relies on the procedure that is executed each time. The Only role of this procedure is to execute another procedure passing it's parameters without knowing how many parameters they are or what data type.

Comment: NB: This is a bad idea from a security point of view - you're basically providing a proxy to execute anything on the SQL server.

Comment: I understand the security issue, So there is no other way, I thought that because I can pass the stored procedure dynamically and executed within another procedure in sql server, they had also developed a special variable say @params as paramtype were i can pass my variables wraped into one.
Still the idea of passing a special variable say array of values and types would be nice.
Anyway the old way is the only way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really clear what the point of your wrapper procedure is (auditing? debugging?), and it seems like a very awkward solution. If you explain why you want to do this, someone may have a completely different and hopefully better solution.

The biggest issue with your proposal is that you can only pass parameters as strings and that means you have to handle all the escaping, data conversion/formatting and SQL injection issues that come with [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). It would be much better to call each procedure directly, passing correctly typed parameters from your calling code.

Having said all that, if you really want to do it then you can do something like this:

```
create proc dbo.ExecuteProcedure
    @ProcedureName sysname,
    @Parameters nvarchar(max),
    @Debug bit = 0x0,
    @Execute bit = 0x1
as
set nocount on
begin

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'exec ' + quotename(@ProcedureName) + ' ' + @Parameters

if @Debug = 0x1 print @sql

if @Execute = 0x1 exec(@sql)

end
go

exec dbo.ExecuteProcedure 'dbo.SomeProc', '@p1 = 1, @p2 = ''themhz''s proc''', 0x1, 0x0
```

You should also have a look at [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), which does almost exactly what you want, but it needs to have all the parameter data types too, which you say is not possible in your scenario.

Comment: Ok thank you for you time, this was the old way, I accept your answer because it seems that there is no other way yet and the only way is the way you propose despite the fact of the security issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the stored procedure name in a varchar field in your client table
2. Retrieve the SP name and assign it to a parameter ( spName) when the         client is chosen.
3. In code create a function that returns a string

   function PassStoredProcedureName(spName as string) as string

   return spName

   end function
4. Set your dataset to "Stored Procedure"
5. Open a dataset Expression window
6. Enter =Code.PassStoredProcedureName(Parameters!spName.value)

When you chose a client, the spName will be assigned to the parameter. When the dataset executes, it will pass the parameter to the function, which will pass the spName to the dataset.

I use this to execute custom stored procedures for clients when the same stored procedure will not work for all clients.

Be sure to normalize the aliased field names so that data retrieval to a report does not break.

Your stored procedures should always have the same parameter requirements even if they are not needed.