# formatting a string param to be the IN statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameters

I have a bit of code:

```
declare @GroupNames nvarchar(1024)
EXEC Utility.dbo.Get_ADGroups_ForUser 'rwm132' ,@GroupNames output
print @GroupNames
```

the print statement looks like this :

```
'vQAHR','vQAResearch','vQAICT','vQAAdvancement','vAllResearch','vAllStudent','vQATeachLearn','vQAFinance','vQAHR'

(0 row(s) affected)
```

I have a predicate

```
WHERE
     (
RLP.ALL_GROUP_NAME IN  ( @GroupNames )  
 )
```

this doesn't seem to work how should I format the string with ' so that it 
works. If I copy that string and paste it in place of @GroupNames in the predicate it works file just something in the substitution that seems to screw it up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing dynamic parameters to a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923567/passing-dynamic-parameters-to-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a split string function

In Sql Server 2016 you can use [**`STRING_SPLIT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt684588.aspx) function

```
WHERE
(
RLP.ALL_GROUP_NAME IN  ( select value from STRING_SPLIT(@GroupNames,','))  
 )
```

For previous version use any one of the method from below link

[**Split strings the right way – or the next best way**](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

In case you are appending *single quotes* for each value inside the string then use this

```
WHERE
(
RLP.ALL_GROUP_NAME IN  ( select stuff(stuff(value,1,1,''),len(value)-1,1,'') from STRING_SPLIT(@GroupNames,','))  
 )
```

or you can use `Dynamic Sql`, Considering there wont be any *Sql injection* since it is a procedure output

```
declare @sql varchar(max)=''
set @sql ='
select ..
WHERE
RLP.ALL_GROUP_NAME IN  ( '+@str+') '

exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

If not 2016, you can use a TVF to split or parse the string

```
-- Notice the single quotes surrounding each item are not necessary 
Declare @GroupNames varchar(max) = 'vQAHR,vQAResearch,vQAICT,vQAAdvancement,vAllResearch,vAllStudent,vQATeachLearn,vQAFinance,vQAHR'

Select A.* 
 From  YourTable A
 Where RLP.ALL_GROUP_NAME in (Select RetVal from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@GroupNames,','))
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

Now, Just for fun, if you don't want a UDF, you can

```
Select A.*
 From  YourTable A
 Where RLP.ALL_GROUP_NAME In (Select Item=LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                                From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@GroupNames,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                             )
```