# Executing Dynamic SQL that contains a stored procedure call

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am making a table that contains a 'stack' of queries to run as strings. The strings are stored procedures with parameters but whenever I exec them, I get an error saying it can't find the stored procedure.

For example, I have a stored procedure called InterfaceQuery that accepts one int parameter and this works fine:

```
exec InterfaceQuery @Facility_fk = 1044
```

but when I put it in a string and execute the string like so:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000) = 'InterfaceQuery @Facility_fk = 1044'
exec @sqlCommand
```

I get an error

> Could not find stored procedure 'InterfaceQuery @Facility_fk = 1044'

I have also tried `sp_executesql`, but can't think of a good way to do the parameters because each procedure will have a variety of parameters.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need brackets when executing a string e.g. `exec(@sqlCommand)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing dynamic parameters to a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923567/passing-dynamic-parameters-to-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: That statement isn't even dynamic. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Dale Burrel, the brackets were what I was missing, exec(@sqlCommand) works

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sp_executesql` instead of `exec` as below.

```
DECLARE @paramDef nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @paramVal int

set @paramDef = N'@Facility_fk int'
set @paramVal = 1044

exec sp_executesql N'dbo.InterfaceQuery @Facility_fk', @paramDef, @Facility_fk=@paramVal
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dale Burrel, the brackets were what I was missing, `exec(@sqlCommand)` works